# Quantmod R :specifyModel() Error: NG3(xts object) download failed after two attempts

Tags: r, quantmod

```
 > sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 18.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.7.4 quantmod_0.4-13 TTR_0.23-4      xts_0.11-2     
[5] zoo_1.8-4      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.1  magrittr_1.5    tools_3.5.1     curl_3.2       
 [5] yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_1.0.0      stringi_1.2.4   grid_3.5.1     
 [9] stringr_1.3.1   lattice_0.20-38
>
```

I run this code:

```
 Lesson4 <- function()
 {
  # Dec 9 2018 - next steps to learn in order to 
 # perform backtest
 #steps .5?? specifymodel() function
 #steps 1 buildmodel() function
 #steps 2 trademodel() function
 #steps 3 call functions to get model performance 
 #details

library("lubridate")
library("quantmod")
library(xts)
setwd("/home/gabe/Learn")

NG2 <- read.csv("NGdec18.csv",
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
               header = FALSE)

dates <- as.character(NG2$V1)
dates2 <- as.POSIXct(dates, format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
NG2[, 1] <- dates2

   names(NG2)[2]  <- paste("NG3.Open")
   names(NG2)[3]  <- paste("NG3.High")
   names(NG2)[4]  <- paste("NG3.Low")
   names(NG2)[5]  <- paste("NG3.Close")
   names(NG2)[6]  <- paste("NG3.Volume")
   NG2 <- subset(NG2,  NG2$V1 > "2018-10-01")

   NG3 <- xts(NG2[-1], order.by = NG2[, 1])

   print(c("class=", class(NG3)))
   print(NG3[1:2,])
   print(head(OpHi(NG3)))
   print(head(OpCl(NG3)))
   specifyModel(Next(OpCl(NG3)) ~ OpHi(NG3))


 }
```

It works fine when I use same code with GE stock prices from yahoo...but when I use this intraday data from a csv file it fails. However i checked and the data "NG3" is a `xts` file. I also carefully named the columns because that was a problem. I'm also using the simplest little model I can think of and it seems each of the parts of the silly model are legit objects. You can see that in the output:

```
> Lesson4()
[1] "class=" "xts"    "zoo"   

 NG3.Open NG3.High NG3.Low NG3.Close NG3.Volume
2018-10-01 00:10:00    3.104    3.107   3.104     3.107         17
2018-10-01 00:20:00    3.107    3.107   3.107     3.107          5
                        OpHi.NG3
      2018-10-01 00:10:00 0.0009664948
      2018-10-01 00:20:00 0.0000000000
      2018-10-01 00:30:00 0.0000000000
      2018-10-01 00:40:00 0.0000000000
      2018-10-01 00:50:00 0.0000000000
       2018-10-01 01:00:00 0.0003226847
                         OpCl.NG3
       2018-10-01 00:10:00  0.0009664948
       2018-10-01 00:20:00  0.0000000000
       2018-10-01 00:30:00 -0.0016097875
       2018-10-01 00:40:00  0.0000000000
       2018-10-01 00:50:00  0.0000000000
       2018-10-01 01:00:00  0.0003226847
    Warning: NG3 download failed; trying again.
     Show Traceback

     Rerun with Debug
     Error: NG3 download failed after two attempts. Error 
    message:
    HTTP error 404.
```

I don't even need internet connection for this...why is it telling me HTTP error?more importantly...can anyone help me get this `specifymodel()` function to work without this error?

here is the traceback:

```
9.
stop(Symbols.name, " download failed after two attempts. Error", 
    " message:\n", attr(dl, "condition")$message, call. = FALSE) 
8.
getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "NG3", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE, 
    warnings = TRUE, auto.assign = TRUE) 
7.
do.call(paste("getSymbols.", symbol.source, sep = ""), list(Symbols = current.symbols, 
    env = env, verbose = verbose, warnings = warnings, auto.assign = auto.assign, 
    ...)) 
6.
getSymbols(V, env = env) 
5.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
4.
lapply(vars, function(V) {
    if (!exists(V)) {
        getSymbols(V, env = env)
    } ... 
3.
getModelData(new.quantmod, na.rm = na.rm) 
2.
specifyModel(Next(OpCl(NG3)) ~ OpHi(NG3)) at ghtest.R#170
1.
Lesson4()
```

also here is the head() of the original csv file NGdec18.csv:

```
                 V1    V2    V3    V4    V5  V6
1 20180924  18:00:00 3.102 3.106 3.102 3.104 118
2 20180924  18:10:00 3.102 3.103 3.101 3.103   6
3 20180924  18:20:00 3.103 3.103 3.103 3.103   0
4 20180924  18:30:00 3.103 3.103 3.103 3.103   0
5 20180924  18:40:00 3.103 3.103 3.103 3.103   0
6 20180924  18:50:00 3.105 3.105 3.105 3.105   1
```

csv file can be downloaded here:
http://www.sharecsv.com/s/53f6728024686c49d2fc81273a7f7464/NGdec18.csv

```
  Lesson4 <- function()
 {

     library("lubridate")
     library("quantmod")
     library(xts)
     setwd("/home/gabe/Learn")

     NG2 <- read.csv("NGdec18.csv",
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                     header = FALSE)

     dates <- as.character(NG2$V1)
     dates2 <- as.POSIXct(dates, format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
     NG2[, 1] <- dates2

     names(NG2)[2]  <- paste("NG3.Open")
     names(NG2)[3]  <- paste("NG3.High")
     names(NG2)[4]  <- paste("NG3.Low")
     names(NG2)[5]  <- paste("NG3.Close")
     names(NG2)[6]  <- paste("NG3.Volume")
  #  setSymbolLookup("symbol.lookup" = FALSE)
    # options("getSymbols.sources" = "csv")
     setSymbolLookup(NG3='csv')
     NG3 <- xts(NG2[-1], order.by = NG2[, 1])

     print(c("class=", class(NG3)))
     print(NG3[1:2,])
     print(head(OpHi(NG3)))
     print(head(OpCl(NG3)))
     specifyModel(Next(OpCl(NG3)) ~ OpHi(NG3))
 }
```

I tried your suggestions and one of my own...and it got rid of the 'yahoo' source problem, but still get this error:

```
Error in `dimnames<-.xts`(`*tmp*`, value = dn) : 
 length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

with traceback:

```
11.
`dimnames<-.xts`(`*tmp*`, value = dn) 
10.
`dimnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = dn) 
9.
`colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = paste(toupper(gsub("\\^", "", Symbols[[i]])), 
    col.names, sep = ".")) 
8.
getSymbols.csv(Symbols = "NG3", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE, 
    warnings = TRUE, auto.assign = TRUE) 
7.
do.call(paste("getSymbols.", symbol.source, sep = ""), list(Symbols = current.symbols, 
    env = env, verbose = verbose, warnings = warnings, auto.assign = auto.assign, 
    ...)) 
6.
getSymbols(V, env = env) 
5.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
4.
lapply(vars, function(V) {
    if (!exists(V)) {
        getSymbols(V, env = env)
    } ... 
3.
getModelData(new.quantmod, na.rm = na.rm) 
2.
specifyModel(Next(OpCl(NG3)) ~ OpHi(NG3)) at ghtest.R#166
1.
Lesson4()
```

Comment: The traceback suggests you need to be reading `?getSymbols`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a good area to re-read in the traceback. However, I've read the ?getSymbols. Do you have a specific page or url you think addresses my problem?  I am not comprehending something that must be obvious to others. I managed to get the csv into xts format and changed the DF into a xts object...but I can't just use that xts object as an argument now. It seems to want me to get it from Yahoo or a csv file...yet if I write a xts object to csv....and then try to call it with getSymbol() , it again says : Error in charToDate(x) :

Comment: Didn't you see a parameter whose default was TRUE that specified getting data from an external source?  Do note: you do not have a [MCVE] because that csv file is sitting on your device only.

Comment: 1. The csv file url posted now. 2. no i did not see anything about "external source"...when I look at help I see :getSymbols(Symbols = NULL, 
           env = parent.frame(),
           reload.Symbols = FALSE,
           verbose = FALSE,
           warnings = TRUE,
           src = "yahoo",
           symbol.lookup = TRUE,
           auto.assign = getOption('getSymbols.auto.assign',TRUE),
           ...) and "additional parameters" with zero info on that

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess since your code runs without error on my Linux box running R 3.5.1 and here's the OS and packages part of sessioninfo():

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so
   #omitted locales
other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.7.4 quantmod_0.4-13 TTR_0.23-4      xts_0.11-2      zoo_1.8-4      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.1  magrittr_1.5    tools_3.5.1     curl_3.2        yaml_2.2.0     
 [6] Rcpp_1.0.0      stringi_1.2.4   grid_3.5.1      stringr_1.3.1   lattice_0.20-38
```

So my guess is that you need to set the quantmod option for symbol.lookup to FALSE. I cannot test my theory because my system succeeds with your code but you could try:

```
setSymbolLookup("symbol.lookup" = FALSE)
```

The goal is to get teh symbol lookup default to NOT use "yahoo". At least it didn't cause an errors or break your `Lesson4` code. Admittedly it wasn't a very interesting result:

```
quantmod object:        Build date:   

Model Specified: 
     Next(OpCl(NG3)) ~ OpHi(NG3) 

Model Target:  Next.OpCl.NG3         Product:  NG3 
Model Inputs:   

Fitted Model: 

    None Fitted
```

After looking at the code for getSymbols I have yet another idea:

```
options("getSymbols.sources" = "csv")
getOption("getSymbols.sources")
[1] "csv"
```

Comment: do you think my problem could be a linux mint issue? or installed something incorrectly?

Comment: Not really sure. Seems unlikely. Did you try the last suggestion? According to my reading of the code this _should_ result in a call to `getSymbols.csv` rather than to `getSymbols.yahoo`. Perhaps one of the maintainers will see this when they come in tomorrow morning and check the [quantmod] tag.

Comment: I tried all 3: setSymbolLookup("symbol.lookup" = FALSE) & setSymbolLookup(NG3='csv') both eliminate any yahoo calls...but result in the in the dimnames error  I added to the end of the post

Comment: options("getSymbols.sources" = "csv") actually still results in the yahoo call problem

Comment: @GabeHarris, short answer, don't use `SpecifyModel`. Long answer, the model part of quantmod has never been fully developed, is unfinished / contains bugs. The maintainer of quantmod will not update this modelling part of the code, due to time constraints. You can find several open issues on the quantmod github page. The code of 42 works, but the first time you use SpecifyModel it tries to find the ticker via yahoo even when `setSymbolLookup("symbol.lookup" = FALSE)` has been set. At least it does it on my machine. It is an example of a partly buggy code.